# How do I get the associated form object of data from SQL data

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a small application that has a `ToolStrip`. When the user clicks on any of the buttons, a form needs to be opened. I would like to have the `ToolStrip` dynamically loaded.

The table that the `ToolStrip` will be loaded from has the following scheme:

```
Table "toolstripitem" 
---------------------
 ID
 form_object  (varchar)
 image_url
 item_order
```

How do I associate the `form_object` string with the form within my application?

**Example**:

A form with the name `frmStore` exists in application, the `form_object` is returned as a string with value of `"frmStore"`, how do I associate that string to the `frmStore` form?

Comment: Er, what type *is* form_object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try do it this way:

```
// here goes fully qualified name,
// format: TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass+NestedClass,MyAssembly
string typeName = "WindowsFormsApplication4.frmStore,WindowsFormsApplication4";
Type frm = Type.GetType(typeName);
Form f = Activator.CreateInstance(frm) as Form;
if (f != null)
    f.Show();
```

**Added**:

typeName format:
WindowsFormsApplication4 - namespace,
frmStore - class name,
WindowsFormsApplication4 - assembly name

It works for forms that have parameterless constructor which usually is true. For different type constructor check [Activator.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)